# Why the variable is not visible from the imported file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, node-mysql

There are a code in main.js:

```
var test_mysql = require('./test_mysql.js')
... //some code
    before(function(){
        test_mysql.preparingDB(test_mysql.SQL_query.clear_data); // or test_mysql.preparingDB(SQL_query.clear_data); 
    });
```

A code in test_mysql.js:

```
var SQL_query = require('./SQL_query.js');
...//some code
exports.preparingDB = function(query){
    connection.connect(function(err){
        if (err){
            console.error('Error connecting: ' + err.stack);
            return;
        }
        console.log('Connected as id ' + connection.threadId);
    });
    console.log(query);  
    connection.query(query, function(err){
        if (err){       
            console.error('Error: ' + err.stack);
            throw err; /*не уверена, что оба сработают*/
        }
        console.log('Database preparation completed');
    });
```

A code in SQL_query.js:

```
exports.clear_data = 'SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;  -- \
TRUNCATE TABLE `billing_payment_gateway`;  -- \
TRUNCATE TABLE `fos_user`;  -- \
TRUNCATE TABLE `billing_account_has_product`;  -- \
TRUNCATE TABLE `billing_account`;  -- \
TRUNCATE TABLE `billing_product`; -- \
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;'
```

---

When I try to run main.js, I'm recieve Error. In first case is `TypeError: Cannot read property 'clear_data' of undefined`.
In another case is `ReferenceError: SQL_query is not defined`.

Why? What issue?

P.S. Ok. Explain to me please. someone. In `test_mysql.js` also require `var mysql = require('mysql');` Why this module is visible in `main.js`????

Comment: Remove the `var` from the declaration and check it out. make SQL_query global as `window.SQL_query`. Check it out, see if it works

Comment: are there any other ways to solve this problem? I don't really want to pollute the global namespace.

Comment: The answer given by @NirLevy should do the trick.

Comment: If this is the only solution, it's sad. Why JS does not automatically tightens the required dependencies, for me remains a mystery. One I think it is strange?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `test_mysql.js` you export only `preparingDB`, so therefore this is the only thing from this module that's available from outside.

You should also export `SQL_query` variable if you want it available from requiring modules

Comment: But test_mysql.js queries SQL_query.js doesn't that mean that during the boot test_mysql.js in the cache , it will query the SQL_query.js and it will also be added to the cache? This behavior seems logical to me.

Comment: I don't like the idea of multiple use dependencies. How I can do better than that to solve this problem?